# How to execute a command in python file?

Tags: python, command, google-colaboratory

Currently executing this in google colab:

```
!python myfile.py   --size 45  --file textfile.txt --data_folder somePath/folder
```

How can I put the above command into a python file (executeNow.py), so that I'll be able to run this in google colab:

```
!python executeNow.py
```

Namely what should be written inside execute.py so that the above to commands will be equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the module `subprocess` for that. Put this in your `executeNow.py`:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["python", "myfile.py", "--size", "45", "--file", "textfile.txt", "--data_folder", "somePath/folder"])
```

However, for this task I'd recommend using a bash script: write this into `executeNow.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
python myfile.py --size 45 --file textfile.txt --data_folder somePath/folder
```

Optionally, make that file executable:

```sh
!chmod +x executeNow.sh
```

Then run this in Colab:

```sh
!sh executeNow.sh
```

If you did the optional part, you can contract the above command slightly shorter:

```sh
!./executeNow.sh
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! But I need to execute it inside the py file. So I'm looking for a way to do that.

Comment: @DannyDan if that's what you need, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: may you please help with: %pip install -qr requirement.txt